# MVC DropDownListFor - "Object reference not set to instance of object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm getting a null reference error with my dropdownlistfor in my partial view. I can't seem to find what I'm missing or doing wrong to get an empty object reference. 
**ModelCode:**

**CommonHerpNames.cs**

```
public class CommonHerpNames
    {
        [Key]
        public int CommonHerpId { get; set; }

        public string HerpName { get; set; }
}
```

**NewReptileViewModel.cs**

```
public class NewReptileViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CommonHerpNames> CommonAnimalNames { get; set; }
    public ReptileModel ReptileModel { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
  public ActionResult _AddReptile()
    {
        var commonAnimalTypes = _context.CommonHerps.ToList();
        var viewModel = new NewReptileViewModel
        {
           CommonAnimalNames = commonAnimalTypes
        };            

        return PartialView("_AddReptile", viewModel);
    }
```

**Partial ViewCode:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReptileModel.CommonHerpTypeId, new SelectList(Model.CommonAnimalNames, "CommonHerpId", "HerpName"), "Select Animal")
</div>
```

**Main View Code:**

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_addReptiles")
</div>
```

For the record, I know my CommonHerps context is good as I recently completed an **Add-Migration** and **Update-Database -Verbose**.

Comment: You are not creating an instance of ReptileModel in your view model.  You are dereferencing ReptileModel to get the Id in your view, but ReptileModel is null.  You probably want to create an instance of the ReptileModel in your NewReptileViewModel constructor.

Comment: How am I not. I'm referencing it after ienumerable

Comment: How are you calling this partial view?

Comment: Using @html.partial("_addReptiles") between a set of did tags in my main page

Comment: @Alex - You are *DECLARING* ReptileModel, you are not *INSTANTIATING* it.  You are creating a variable, of type ReptileModel which is null by default.  Do what I said, and create a new instance in your constructor.

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call a controller method - you need `@Html.Action()` for that (yo need t add the relevant code in your question)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke If you want to make your comment the answer I will mark it. That solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Html.Partial()` does not call your server method. It just renders the partial view (passing the model in the main view to the partial) and the error is thrown because `CommonAnimalNames` is `null` and you cannot initialize a new `SelectList` for a `null`.

Change the code in the main view to

```
@Html.Action("_AddReptile") // add controller name as 2nd parameter if necessary
```

or

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_AddReptile"); }
```

which will call your `_AddReptile()` method, which will in turn initialize your view model and set the value of `CommonAnimalNames`.

You may also want to consider marking `_AddReptile()` with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to prevent it being called by the browser.